# Parenthesis/Brackets Matching and Maximum Elements using Stack algorithm

Tags: data-structures, stack

**Question**: Suppose we are looking to process this expression  `( [ ( { [ ] [ ] } ( ( ( ) ) ) ) { } ] )` using a **stack**. What is the maximum number of elements on the stack at any one time?

I understand that stack runs in LIFO order, so I am not sure how to match that with maximum number of elements and how does that relate to the expression anyway. The question is unclear for me. What do you think please?

I tried to answer it and got 9, but I found that maximum number of elements on the stack at any one time is 6 based on answer I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got an opening bracket, you put it on the stack. If you got a closing bracket which matches the opening bracket on the top of the stack, you pop this bracket from stack, else you put in on the stack. In this expression the stack would look like this:

- `(`
- `( [`
- `( [ (`
- `( [ ( {`
- `( [ ( { [`
- `( [ ( {`
- `( [ ( { [`
- `( [ ( {`
- `( [ (`
- `( [ ( (`
- `( [ ( ( (`
- `( [ ( ( ( (`
- `( [ ( ( (`
- `( [ ( (`
- `( [ (`
- `( [`
- `( [ {`

Comment: Thanks, but how you can conclude you can have at most 6 elements based on that please? And how you can match current bracket added to a stack with previously added bracket given that stack has only push and pop operations, which means you can not search in between the elements of stack?

Comment: After every operation just check the number of elements in stack. State `( [ ( ( ( (` has 6 elements and that's the maximum (based on expression in your post). When using stack you only have access to the element on the top and that's enough. You can just check if this bracket matches the one in the expression.

Comment: Thanks! I thought by elements is meant numbers! So, elements here means brackets please?

Comment: Yes, that's how I understand it.

Comment: Sounds correct. I just got confused to what elements meant. Thank you again.